# Line height in comments is too small

Tags: bug, status-planned, design

Line height in comments is too small and descenders are partially covered by author's name background:

[image: Error example]

Viewed with Chrome 46 on Windows 7 on [this comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111919/split-a-string-into-chunks-of-the-same-length/111925#comment206522_111925) (but it's the same everywhere when author's name is below text with descenders).

Comment: Do you have a link to this comment so that others can test it?

Comment: Yeap, I see this now. Added to my todo list, fix will be ready probably tommorow.